# IndexError: index 38037 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 35062

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

please don't mark it as duplicate, I know there are similar questions but I was unable to solve the issue with already posted solutions mine is a different scenario.
I am training a Naive Bayes Classifier against a data frame, I got the data frame after label encoding string values using the below code:

```
df["Block"] = df["Block"].astype('category')
df["Block"] = df["Block"].cat.codes
df["Type"] = df["Type"].astype('category')
df["Type"] = df["Type"].cat.codes
df["Date"] = df["Date"].astype('category')
df["Date"] = df["Date"].cat.codes
```

Data frame after applying label encoding:

[image]

The training part worked fine but while testing the below data frame I got the error:- "IndexError: index 38037 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 35062"

[image]

Full error Description:-

[image]

df_Xtr shape = (1122266, 2)
df_Xte shape = (258818, 2)

Hope you solve the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you reset the index? you must be shuffling the data before splitting into train and test data so your indices are not in sequential way. Please reset them by using `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: yes, I tried using reset_index but the error remains the same.

Comment: should be `pred = clf.predict(df_Xte2) ` you are using `df_Xte`. please check

Comment: @Pygirl I thought converting df_Xte to a NumPy array might solve the issue that's the reason I used df_Xte2, but even after using df_Xte2, the error persists.

Comment: I guess you may need to reshape. `clf_pf.predict([[-0.8, -1]])` Do you have passed data in this form? `[[<data1-x>, <data1-y>], [<data2-x>, <data2-y>]]`.

Comment: @Pygirl yes I had passed the inputs in the above-mentioned form. I am getting this error only when the date column is included, if I discard the Date column the error is vanishing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227577/discussion-between-pygirl-and-meghsat).